# Get id from form

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, forms

I have products on the page. Every product its form. And I keep Id product in the hidden input.

```
@foreach($product as $p)
    <form>
        <div class="col-lg-2 product">
            <h3>{{$p->name}}</h3>
            <img src="{{$p->image}}" width="200" height="200"><br>
            <h3>{{$p->price}}</h3>
            <button type="submit" onclick="addProductInCart()" >Добавить в корзину</button>
            <input type="hidden"  name = "idVal" value = "{{$p->id}}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
        </div>
    </form>
@endforeach
```

I need to get the product id, which I choose, in JS.

For example:

[image]

I will choose Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 and I must get Id = 1. If I will choose Meizu I must get Id = 2. 
Now I get both Ids every time.

My JS code:

```
function addProductInCart() {


    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($('form').serializeArray()); 
    var product = 1;
    var token = $("input[name=_token]").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addToCart",
        data: {"_token": token, "product": product},
        success: function (result) {
            $("#product-count").html(result);

        }
    })
}
```

And result:
[image]

I need only one Id, not both. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this` keyword to refer to the current clicked element, then go up to the parent and select the related input with name `idVal` that contains the `if` of the current product :

```
var product_id = $(this).parent().find('[name="idVal"]').val();
```

And you've to pass the `this` to your function in `onClick` :

```
<button type="button" onclick="addProductInCart(this)">Добавить в
```

корзину

```js
function addProductInCart(self) {
  event.preventDefault();

  alert($(self).parent().find('[name="idVal"]').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="col-lg-2 product">
    <h3>name 1</h3>
    <img src="" width="200" height="200"><br>
    <h3>111</h3>
    <button type="button" onclick="addProductInCart(this)">Добавить в корзину</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="idVal" value="1">
  </div>
</form>
<form>
  <div class="col-lg-2 product">
    <h3>name 2</h3>
    <img src="" width="200" height="200"><br>
    <h3>222</h3>
    <button type="button" onclick="addProductInCart(this)">Добавить в корзину</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="idVal" value="2">
  </div>
</form>
<form>
  <div class="col-lg-2 product">
    <h3>name 3</h3>
    <img src="" width="200" height="200"><br>
    <h3>333</h3>
    <button type="button" onclick="addProductInCart(this)">Добавить в корзину</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="idVal" value="3">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Now I get undefined value

Comment: Your decision is working but the handler is triggered repeatedly too

Comment: I removed submit handler. Now i have only onclick event. It's okay?

Comment: Yes updated my post, you need to use `type="button"` instead since you're already submitting the data inside the click event.

Comment: Can you tell me how is working you code with "self"? I have some experience in JS and PHP, but can't understand for what this keyword.

Comment: The `self` keyword will be passed to the function `addProductInCart` as an argument that contains the clicked object instance, then we convert it to jQuery object `$(self)` then go up to the parent `div` using `.parent()` and get the hidden field value by `.find('[name="idVal"]').val()`.

Comment: So if you want to serialize the related data you've to use `$(self).closest('form').serializeArray()`, to serialize the parent form of the clicked button.

Comment: Thank you so much)

Comment: Glad I could help brother.

Answer (score 2):

you dont have to store it in a hidden field just to retrive it in addproductInCart() function

you can pass the value with the funtion like following

```
addProductInCart(<?= $p->id ?>)
```

and in function you can get id by following

```
addProductInCart($id)
{
    alert($id);
}
```

Comment: So simple  and I did not think of it :D

Comment: You can't use it this way since you need more information about the clicked button to target the related form.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form class="product-form">
        <div class="col-lg-2 product">
            <h3>{{$p->name}}</h3>
            <img src="{{$p->image}}" width="200" height="200"><br>
            <h3>{{$p->price}}</h3>
            <button type="submit" onclick="addProductInCart(this)" >Добавить в корзину</button>
            <input type="hidden"  name = "idVal" value = "{{$p->id}}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
        </div>
    </form>
```

Give form a class. Now you can fetch the values associated with it.

```
$('.product-form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());

 var product = 1;
    var token = $("input[name=_token]").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addToCart",
        data: {"_token": token, "product": product},
        success: function (result) {
            $("#product-count").html(result);

        }
    })

  return false;
});
```